# How to dynamically control class of parent element in Angular 2+ on input focus?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a series of input boxes that are inside of an element and I want to make the parent element of the input boxes to individually have a border based on where the mouse is focused.  The code looks like this:

**HTML** (just one of the input elements, because they are all coded the same way):

```
<div class="parent-element">
  <input type="text"
    [class.bordered]="myBooleanVariable"
    (focus)="addBorder()"
    (blur)="removeBorder()"
  />
</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
addBorder() {
  this.myBooleanVariable = true;
}

removeBorder(event) {
  this.myBooleanVariable = false;
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when the `bordered` class is applied on `focus`, all of the `.parent-element` divs get borders since `myBooleanVariable` is either true or false.  I want to avoid making static variables like `myBooleanVariable1`, `myBooleanVariable2`, etc.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add and remove classes using JS from the component methods, for that all you need, it's create a template variable for your wrapper and paste this variable in the method params, in the method you get HTMLElement of the wrapper

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="parent-element" *ngFor="let i of items" #wrap>
      <input type="text"
        (focus)="addBorder(wrap)"
        (blur)="removeBorder(wrap)"
      />
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  items = [1,2,3];

  addBorder(wrap: HTMLElement) {
    wrap.classList.add('bordered');
  }

  removeBorder(wrap: HTMLElement) {
    wrap.classList.remove('bordered');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @izmaylovdev!

Answer (score 1):

If you give each input an index, you can have one local variable that controls the reference to the focussed input.

```
foccused: number | string;
```

Then you can use `[ngClass]` to apply the border to your parent element with something like:

```
<div class="parent-element" [ngClass]="{ 'bordered' : isFocussed(1) }">
```

So instead of setting a boolean, you set a number with `addBorder(1)`, e.g..

```
<div class="parent-element" [ngClass]="{ 'bordered' : isFocussed(1) }">
   <input type="text"
   (focus)="addBorder(1)"
   (blur)="removeBorder()"/>
</div>
```

Where `addBorder()` becomes:

```
addBorder(index: number) {
  this.foccused = index;
}
```

Here's a stackblitz that shows you how: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqwqjd

You can do some more fancy things with `ElementRef` and `Renderer2`, but for what you need, the above should be sufficient.

This way comes with the added bonus of being extendable in a loop, if you had an array of inputs you wanted to output one after another, just replace index with the index provided by `*ngFor`